# Java '}' error when creating a class

Tags: java, syntax

I've just started to learn Java and I've been getting syntax errors so I just wondering if anyone can spot the error? The error says I need to remove '}' and in the other line, it says to add '}'.

```
package car;

public class Car {
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    boolean isNew;
    double miles;
    String owner;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car newCar = new Car();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `void main` needs to be inside the class

```
package car;

public class Car {
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    boolean isNew;
    double miles;
    String owner;


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Car newCar = new Car();
   }

}
```

Comment: And this is a super simple typo error - worth closing - not answering.

Answer (score 0):

Main method should be part of the class, put it inside class declaration. In Java, methods exist only in context of some class.